# sending json data to server

Tags: php, jquery, json

I have this code to send data:

```
function insert_new_image()
{
    var ids = [];
    $('.be-imagecontainer').each(function(i){
        ids[i] =$(this).find('span').text();
    });

    var jsonids = {'ids' : ids}

    var url  = base_url + 'ajax/get_new_images';
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        data : {'ids' : jsonids},
        success : function(response)
        {
            $('#be-images ul').prepend(response)
        },
        dataType: 'html'
    });
}
```

and this code from the server(PHP):

```
function get_new_images()
    {
        $ids = json_decode($_GET['ids'], true);

        echo Kohana::debug($ids);
    }
```

the server responds with a

```
null
```

how can I make this work? I am trying to send a json data containing an array of ids to the server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use json2.js to encode the Javascript object as JSON:

```
 data: {ids: JSON.stringify(jsonids)};
```

See [this post](http://ejohn.org/blog/the-state-of-json/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

The data you send back isn't in JSON format, it should be a PHP array by the time your script reads it.

Either use : `var jsonids = "{'ids' : ids}"` (in JS) or `$ids = $_GET['ids'];` (in PHP)

Answer (score 0):

Have you [var_dump](http://www.php.net/var_dump) the $_GET variable? Maybe you aren't sending the right thing. Also check php.log

Another question, Kohana what kind of thing is responding?